# How to count events UP TO certains conditions that invole datetime

Tags: r, date, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have a dataset that has the IDs of certain individuals that tried to breach a private network connection, there are only two types of breaches "X" and "Y" and the dataset will let you know if the attempt was successful (1) or unsuccessful (0) I have to compute how many times a person has tried to breach the network UP TO their first successful breach of type X and/or Y.

To illustrate I have to do my analysis as follows:

I have to organize by date in ascending order then count how many times an ID tried to breach the network until this ID had a successful breach and whether it was of type X or type Y
such as:

```
ID  DATE       SUCCESS  TYPE
007 1/01/2021     0       X
007 1/01/2021     0       X
007 1/01/2021     1       X
007 2/01/2021     0       X
007 3/01/2021     1       Y
```

In this table we see that agent 007 made chronological 3 attempts before his FIRST successfully type X breach of the network, and that it only took him one attempt to do a type Y breach of the network

I have been hitting my head against a wall trying to come up with a code that would let me do that calculation for the following dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
dataset<- tibble::tribble(
  ~DATE,            ~ID,    ~SUCCESS,   ~TYPE,
  "19/04/2021", "52952",    "0",    "X",
  "19/04/2021", "46102",    "0",    "X",
  "20/04/2021", "40005",    "1",    "X",
  "20/04/2021", "29872",    "0",    "X",
  "21/04/2021", "52952",    "0",    "X",
  "21/04/2021", "46102",    "1",    "Y",
  "22/04/2021", "46102",    "0",    "X",
  "22/04/2021", "46102",    "1",    "Y",
  "23/04/2021", "46102",    "0",    "Y",
  "23/04/2021", "46102",    "1",    "Y",
  "24/04/2021", "46102",    "0",    "Y",
  "24/04/2021", "40005",    "0",    "Y",
  "25/04/2021", "52952",    "0",    "Y",
  "25/04/2021", "46102",    "1",    "Y",
  "26/04/2021", "40005",    "0",    "X",
  "26/04/2021", "52952",    "1",    "X",
  "27/04/2021", "46102",    "1",    "X",
  "27/04/2021", "40005",    "1",    "X",
  "28/04/2021", "52952",    "1",    "X",
  "28/04/2021", "52952",    "0",    "X",
)
```

What have I done?

I first started by grouping the ID and DATES in order to select the very first attempt of type X and Y that way I know when was the very first attempt giving that this is Zero, and then I have been figuring out a way to select for each ID the "nearest" successful attempt without any luck as I always end up selecting the very last successful attempt but this excessive only calls for the very first attempt... Also, I have to be careful when selecting the first event because there may be cases where the very first attempt is a success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `group_by` both `ID` and `TYPE` and have them arranged by `DATE`, you can get the index of the first row where `SUCCESS` is equal to 1.

Note - you'll have warnings and `Inf` for events where there is no `SUCCESS` of 1 for a given `ID` and `TYPE`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dataset %>%
  mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE, format = "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(ID, TYPE) %>%
  arrange(ID, TYPE, DATE) %>%
  summarise(EVENTS = min(which(SUCCESS == 1)))
```

Both `min` and `which` are base R. Consider the following data subset for 52952 and type "X":

```
2021-04-19 52952 0       X    
2021-04-21 52952 0       X    
2021-04-26 52952 1       X    
2021-04-28 52952 1       X    
2021-04-28 52952 0       X
```

The values for success are 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 when ordered by date.

If you have a vector of those values, `which` will tell you the index or position, where `SUCCESS` is equal to 1. To demonstrate, if I create a vector `vec` with those same values:

```
vec <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
vec
[1] 0 0 1 1 0

which(vec == 1)
[1] 3 4
```

then `which` tells me that indexes/positions 3 and 4 (third and fourth value) satisfy the condition of equaling 1.

Then, `min` is added to take the minimum value. So, for the result from `which` (3 and 4), the minimum value is 3. It follows then that 3 events are needed to reach the first `SUCCESS` value that equals 1.

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   ID [4]
  ID    TYPE  EVENTS
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
1 29872 X        Inf
2 40005 X          1
3 40005 Y        Inf
4 46102 X          3
5 46102 Y          1
6 52952 X          3
7 52952 Y        Inf
```

Comment: Hello Ben I'm fascinated by this code I am just an R student and the simplicity of your code it's just extraordinarily to me, if you don't mind my asking... How is your code exactly counting the events? I guess in the fun min(which(success=)  but what does it exactly do? I went to the tidyverse documentation and I could find this combination of functions I will appreciate if you can let me know... Thank you so much! Your work helped me a lot 10/10

Comment: @R_Student Glad to hear this helped. Please see edited answer for additional explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataset$DATE <- lubridate::dmy(dataset$DATE)

dataset %>%
  arrange(ID, TYPE, DATE) %>%
  group_by(ID, TYPE) %>%
  # creating variable to denote when success status changes
  mutate(RLEID = rleid(SUCCESS == 0)) %>%
  # keeping the row if the attempt was unsuccessful (SUCCESS == 0) and before a successful attempt (RLEID == 1)
  filter(SUCCESS == 0 & RLEID == 1) %>%
  # finding the counts
  summarise(n = n())
```

Some people (ID = 29872 TYPE = X, ID = 40005 TYPE = Y, ID = 52952 TYPE = Y) never had a successful attempt. Did you still want to include them?